# How to concatenate "nested" variables with a string in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have this set of variables:
[image]

My path in request looks like this:
[image]

But when I run the test URL looks like this:
[image]

But what I expect is :
GET http://somehost:9000/v1/customers

So how to concatenate this variable correctly:

```
CUST.LIMITS.URL      ${__V(${ENV}.BASIC.URL)}/customers
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like JMeter has some kind of variable parsing ordering issue when it tries to solve nested variable references.

But **you can workaround** this if you define another "User Defined Variables" element after the one you already have. Then take the "CUST.LIMITS.URL" from the first "User Defined Variables" and add it to the second one.

So you will have something like this:

**First "User Defined Variables":**

```
ENV                  DEV
DEV.BASIC.URL        somehost:9000/v1
QA.BASIC.URL
```

**Second "User Defined Variables":**

```
CUST.LIMITS.URL      ${__V(${ENV}.BASIC.URL)}/customers
```

**In the Request:**

You don't need the ${__V()} call. Just use plain:
`${CUST.LIMITS.URL}`

Answer (score 0):

You can work it around as follows:

1. In the [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) define variables as:

   - `DEV.BASIC.URL` - `somehost:9000/v1`
   - `CUST.LIMITS.URL` - `${DEV.BASIC.URL}/customers`
2. In your HTTP Request sampler you can refer concatenated variable using [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like:

   ```
   ${__eval(${CUST.LIMITS.URL})}
   ```